# Good ECMAScript 2015 way to wrap method of CasperJS.

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, casperjs

With CasperJS begin method of test property of casper object I want to made something like this:

```
casper.test.begin=(function(originalMethod) {
    return function() {
        // some custom logic here. 
        originalMethod.call(this, arguments);
    }
}(casper.test.begin));
```

But I want this to be implemented in properly ECMA 2015 way (I use babel). 
I tried to inherit CasperJS, but I met a bunch of problems. 
I would be grateful for any advice, ideas and recommendations.

Comment: Isn't it implemented properly now? What are you hoping to improve upon?

Comment: It would be nice if I could inherit CasperJS and to modify the behavior of the method in the child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use Facade (aka wrapper)?

```
class MyFacade {

  constructor(legacyLibrary) {
    this.legacyLibrary = legacyLibrary;
  }

  newMethod() {
    this.legacyLibrary.doSomething();
    this.legacyLibrary.doSomethingElse();
  }

}

export default MyFacade;
```

So you will just pass instance of existing class and do whatever you want instead of monkey patching it.